# how to upload multiple images from android to php server example

Tags: upload

I need to upload the multiple images in a folder from android to php server in a for each or for loop. image path should store in database and image source should store in folder.

following what i have tried

```
$jsonarr = $_POST['ImageArr'];
$decodedjson = json_decode($jsonarr,TRUE);
for( $i=0; $i < count($decodedjson); $i++ ) {
    $destdir ="uploads/".$image_unique_no;
    $img = file_get_contents($decodedjson[$i]);    
    file_put_contents( $destdir.substr( $decodedjson[$i], strrpos($decodedjson[$i],'/')), $img);
}
```

Comment: have you tried any thing?

Comment: $jsonarr = $_POST['ImageArr'];

    
  $decodedjson = json_decode($jsonarr,TRUE); 
for($i=0;$i<count($decodedjson);$i++)
  {
   $destdir ="uploads/".$image_unique_no;
   $img=file_get_contents($decodedjson[$i]);
   file_put_contents($destdir.substr($decodedjson[$i], strrpos($decodedjson[$i],'/')), $img);
}

Comment: The above coding only i have implemented in my project

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$filesArray = $_FILES['ImageArr'];

$file_count = count($filesArray['name']);

    for ($i=0; $i< $file_count; $i++)
    {        
        move_uploaded_file($filesArray['tmp_name'][$i], "upload/".time()."_".$filesArray['name'][$i]);
    }

?>

get images array posted from android device.
```

Comment: Hi ankit thanks for your answer. But i want to move the collection of images into separate folder . How to do that.$imageunique = rand().date("Ymd");
  $mkdir = mkdir("uploads/".$imageunique);
 
  $uploads_dir = 'uploads/'.$imageunique."/";
  
  $filesArray = $_FILES['uploaded_file'];
  $file_count = count($filesArray['name']);
  for ($i=0; $i< $file_count; $i++)
  {        
    move_uploaded_file($filesArray['tmp_name'][$i], $uploads_dir.$filesArray['name'][$i]);
  }

Comment: you can change upload directory for every image

Comment: Yes i can change but its not store inside the directory correctly.

Comment: From android the user placing the order for choosing no of images from device to print photos. Its an application. Whenever the user place the order , they will choose the bulk of images for order to print photos, So that bulk images should store as one order as a one folder

Comment: you want to store images according to order no